# Try Again Button That Resets Everything Within A Game To Initial Value

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm beginner at java and am building a simple game with more classes. I want to add Try Again function that would reset everything to initial value as if the program was closed and reopened but without actually doing that. The function must be called from a class that doesn't contain initialization.

Here is my initialization class:

```
public class game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Menu menu;
private GameOver gameover;


//variables
public static int cyclesToWait = 50;
public static int enemiesKilled = 0;
public static int life = 3;
int roundCount = 0;
Timer gamelooptimer;

//objects
Player p;
ControllerEnemy c;
ControllerRocket r;
ControllerExplosion e;


//is it new round or not --> for enemy control
public static enum ROUND{
    INPROGRESS,
    NEW
}

public static enum STATE{
    MENU,
    GAME,
    OVER
};

public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;
public static ROUND Round = ROUND.INPROGRESS;

public game(){

    setFocusable(true);

    gamelooptimer = new Timer(10, this);
    gamelooptimer.start();

    p = new Player(MainClass.width / 2 - 60, 400);
    c = new ControllerEnemy();
    r = new ControllerRocket();
    e = new ControllerExplosion();
    menu = new Menu();
    gameover = new GameOver();

    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(p));
    addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(getBackgroundImage(), 0, 0, null);

    Font fnt = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 22);
    g.setFont(fnt);


    if(State == STATE.GAME){
        p.draw(g2d);
        p.draw(g2d);
        c.draw(g2d);
        r.draw(g2d);
        e.draw(g2d);
        g.drawString("Round: " + roundCount, MainClass.width - 125, 22);
        g.drawString("Enemies Killed: " + enemiesKilled, MainClass.width/2 - 95, 22);
        if(cyclesToWait < 50)
            cyclesToWait++;
    }
    else if (State == STATE.OVER)
        gameover.render(g);
    else
        menu.render(g);


}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    if(State == STATE.GAME){    
        p.update();
        c.update();
        r.update();
    }
    if(Round == ROUND.NEW)
        roundCount += 1; 
}
private Image getBackgroundImage(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Background.png"));
    return i.getImage();
}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor all the game-related initialization code in your constructor to an `initGame` method. Now you can call that method in your constructor, and also have a `reset()` method that calls `initGame()`. Your Try again button should call `resetGame()`.

```
public game(){
    setFocusable(true);

    initGame();
}

public void resetGame() {
    initGame();
}

private void initGame() {
    gamelooptimer = new Timer(10, this);
    gamelooptimer.start();

    p = new Player(MainClass.width / 2 - 60, 400);
    c = new ControllerEnemy();
    r = new ControllerRocket();
    e = new ControllerExplosion();
    menu = new Menu();
    gameover = new GameOver();

    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(p));
    addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
}
```